# Scrolling images by dragging UISlider

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uislider

Iam beginner in IOS Dev. asking about a way to make `UIScrollView` images scrolls by dragging `UISlider` . This is my case :

**Required case :**

when dragging slider , images scrolls on `UIScrollView` . also when scrolling images , slider changes its value accordingly .

**Actual case :**

when scrolling images , slider changes its value accordingly **BUT** when dragging slider images **DONOT** Scroll .

**Here is my code , I wish any one tell me how to scrolling when slider drags .**

Slider `IBAction`

```
- (IBAction)sliding:(UISlider *)sender{
    int slider_value = (int)slider.value;
    NSString *current_page = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i",slider_value];
    current_page_lbl.text = current_page ;
    [self loadPage:slider_value];
    [self loadVisiblePages];
}
```

methods for UIScrollview :

```
- (void)loadPage:(NSInteger)page {
        if (page < 0 || page >= self.pageImages.count) {
            return;
        }

        UIView *pageView = [self.pageViews objectAtIndex:page];
        if ((NSNull*)pageView == [NSNull null]) {

            CGRect frame = self.scrollView.bounds;
            frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
            frame.origin.y = 0.0f;

            UIImageView *newPageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[self.pageImages objectAtIndex:page]];
            newPageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            newPageView.frame = frame;
            [self.scrollView addSubview:newPageView];

            [self.pageViews replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:newPageView];
        }
    }

- (void)purgePage:(NSInteger)page {
    if (page < 0 || page >= self.pageImages.count) {
        // If it's outside the range of what you have to display, then do nothing
        return;
    }


    UIView *pageView = [self.pageViews objectAtIndex:page];
    if ((NSNull*)pageView != [NSNull null]) {
        [pageView removeFromSuperview];
        [self.pageViews replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:[NSNull null]];
    }
}
```

To loadVisiblePage

```
- (void)loadVisiblePages {

    CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
    NSInteger page = (NSInteger)floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x * 2.0f + pageWidth) / (pageWidth * 2.0f));
    NSLog(@"page loaded is %d",page);

    self.pageControl.currentPage = page; 

    NSInteger firstPage = page - 1;
    NSInteger lastPage = page + 1;

    for (NSInteger i=0; i<firstPage; i++) {
         [self purgePage:i];
    }

    for (NSInteger i=firstPage; i<=lastPage; i++) {
         [self loadPage:i];
         slider.value = 21-i ;
         int slider_value = (int)slider.value;
         NSString *current_page = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i",21-slider_value];
         current_page_lbl.text = current_page ;
    }

    for (NSInteger i=lastPage+1; i<self.pageImages.count; i++) {
         [self purgePage:i];
    }
}


- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [self loadVisiblePages];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

uislider is not suitable to use with uiscrollview....for this purpose there is one controll available name UIPagecontrol..
following link is the nice example with code which direct you to how to use it with UIScollview

[UIPagecontroll with UIscollview with code Click Here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-virtual-pages-in-uiscrollview.html)

Comment: well...thanks for your help ... but I have a large number of photos scrolling and I want a slider to quickly navigate through these large no. As I said I'm in my half-way to do that ... except that dragging slider do not scroll images .

Comment: If there are so many images that it would take too long to scroll then you need to be using a different sort of control (like a UICollectionView to show them in a grid/album style).

Comment: thanks a lot ...could you give me any tutorial about using this control .

Comment: @ShymaaOthman i undertstand what you are trying to implement...i have seen above code....and i have find that you have not use ContentOffset property of UIScrollview...this property is used to set the current visible view in uiscollview in X & y coordinate system....here i look at following simple example [Cliclk Here](http://github.com/zbowling/SliderTest/downloads)

Comment: @ShymaaOthman in above example if get any error regurding photo.jpg..just delete that photo.jpg from Supporting files folder in xcode window and just add any other imagefile and rename it as photo.jpg and just run the project

Comment: @ P R J yes ,this is the point -setContentOffset - to set the current visible view when slider changes its value . Thanks :)

Comment: sure you deserve ! but when I try to vote , a pop up message come to say Vote Up requires 15 reputation ... sorry this was my first question and contribution at stackoverflow :)